# Oracle 12c - how to set 'date' column with year quarter?

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

I have a need to create a column in Oracle 12c that will be date column with values:

```
20163
20164
20171
20172
20173
20174
...
```

How to specify that for a column in a create table statement?

thanks.

Comment: Give your column a datatype of char(6).

Comment: why char? how can I add next quarter to a varchar? isn't a varchar slower to deal with than a date?

Comment: Usually a date column should have the datatype `DATE`. There are exceptions, but typically if you store data like this in a string datatype you'll just end up having to sprinkle `to_date(col)` all through your code, plus you'll need a more complex check constraint.

Comment: Jeffrey, I agree with when "usually" is not BI. Ralph Kimbal in his [Data Warehouse Toolkit](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471200247.html) explains why it's preferable to store datetime in two integer fields (one for date, other for time).
So, original question does not have "only one true" answer

Comment: Could store year and quarter in two columns, which makes queries by quarter potentially better.  I think my answer is the best default answer, given OP didn't give any background.

Comment: > Could store year and quarter in two columns
You describe exactly what is typical in BI. Date dimensions are not rare with dozens of fields.

Answer (score 3):

You can model the column as containing dates, constrained to fall only on the first moment of each quarter.

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP
( QUARTER DATE 
    CONSTRAINT IS_QUARTER CHECK ( (QUARTER = TRUNC(QUARTER, 'Q') ) )
)
```

To put values into the table, you need to set the date to the start of the quarter:

```
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ( TO_DATE('2017-04', 'yyyy-mm') );
```

To read values from the table, you can format as you like:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( quarter, 'YYYYQ') FROM temp;
```

Because the underlying column is a date, you can do things like compare it with other dates, etc.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( ADD_MONTHS( quarter, 3 ), 'YYYYQ') FROM temp;
```

Comment: This is a good solution. Note that you don't need to add the day of month as it defaults to the 1st anyway, i.e. `to_date('2017-04','yyyy-mm')`.

Comment: The constraint can be written much simpler: `CHECK (QUARTER = TRUNC(QUARTER, 'Q'))`

Answer (score -2):

Joe!

Such fields as you described are frequently using for monthly periods.

Typicaly they are encoded in integer datatypes.

If you were not on Oracle, Int32 would be perfect.

In Oracle the decision is not so clear.

I would prefer NUMBER(6,0) and simple constraint that field most be less than any possible date in future.

CHAR(6) - is fine too but constraints will be more complex.

Comment: Thanks. How about performance? Would it be better to use Number vs Char when joining or searching on this column?

Comment: I suppose that searching and joining by CHAR(6) and NUMBER(6,0) will be almost indistinguishable even with really big tables.

Insert and update - depends on check constraint you put on field. 
You can: a) no check at all , b) check by numeric diapazon (allows incorrect monthes) c) full check for month correctness

Comment: I checked again - there is no '0' as a 5th digit. But still have a question - can this column be set as a 'date' somehow? (instead of a number)

Comment: Joe,  your field is not date - it's a monthly period, so why do you insist to encode it as date?  Of course, you can use date type and control all "incorrect" values.

Comment: Some people say - do it as 'date'. Other people say - do it as 'number'. Which one do you think should be?

Comment: Joe, 'some people' asked you to disclose some details of your database. 
Do you have operational database or BI ? Anyway it does not matter a lot

Comment: It is both - operational and BI.